# Localization from database in Telerik Reporting

Tags: asp.net, sql, reporting, telerik, telerik-reporting

I am currently testing Telerik Reporting to replace our current report solution which is some kind of scripting tool that pulls the localized version of a term from the database.

Example:

A label called "customer" would have a english definition (Customer) and a french one (Client).
We get the correct definition from the database by calling a function like GetLabel("customer",user_language).

Is there a way to do the same thing except for including each "label" separately in the SQL query of the datasource?

We plan to use Telerik Reporting in an ASP.NET environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way of doing this quite easily.

I only had to use the [User Functions](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/expressions-user-functions.html) that Telerik Reporting already support and then return the correct value.